# how to return a specific JSON object by value

Tags: json, kotlin, indexing

I have my JSON object below

```
{
"test1": 1,
"test2": 2
}
```

Suppose I wanted to return just the "test1" json object. How would I go about doing this? The code I currently have returns everything. Below is the code I have that returns the JSON

```
    fun json(): JSONObject {
    val map: Map<String, Int> = x().map{ it.name to it.age }.toMap() 
    return JSONObject(map)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a **filter** before map with condition you need :

```
x()
 .filter {it.name == "test1"}
 .map { ... }
 .toMap()
```